# How to /setblock an already fully-filled chiseled bookshelf?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know you can access the NBT data of a fully filled chiseled bookshelf with `/data get` and see that all the `slot`s are filled with `minecraft:book`s, but how do you use `/setblock` to place a chiseled bookshelf that is already filled? I tried
`/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:chiseled_bookshelf{Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:book",Count:1b}]}` because that was what I got from the /data get command but it only places an empty bookshelf. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the block state (that a given slot is used) in addition to the NBT data (that a book is in that slot), or otherwise the slot appears to be empty.

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:chiseled_bookshelf[slot_0_occupied=true]{Items:[{Count:1b,Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:book"}]}
```